# Sitemap Generator Links are not Correct for rails sitemap_generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sitemap

Getting a really strange error when leveraging the sitemap_generator in production. Here's my relevant code:

```
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "http://www.wheretoski.co"
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
  User.find_each do |user|
    add users_path(user), :lastmod => user.updated_at
  end
```

This generates locations which look like this:

```
<loc>http://www.wheretoski.co/users.1</loc>
```

I was expecting this to be the output.

```
<loc>http://www.wheretoski.co/users/1</loc>
```

Can someone let me know where I'm going wrong here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I never create Sitemap with this, but this work for me

```
xml.instruct!

xml.urlset :xmlns => "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" do
    ["action_1", "action_2", "action_3"].each do |page|
        xml.url do
            xml.loc send("#{page}_url")
            xml.changefreq "weekly"
            xml.priority 0.2
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhh, stupid error on my part. Leveraging the gem, Rodrigo I'm sure your answer works just fine as well. For this one, you want to make sure your paths are labeled correctly, in my case it should be singular:

```
add user_path(user), :lastmod => user.updated_at
```

Works now :)